# How to get IP address in a connected grpc client?

Tags: grpc

I've tried to build a grpc channel like this:

```
grpc::CreateCustomChannel(serverIP + ":" + serverPort, grpc::SslCredentials(sslOptions), args);
```

I guess that grpc internally bind a IP for grpc client.

**Now, how can I prossibly get the binded IP of client?**

Answer (score 1):

You should add a server interceptor and look at the remote addr attribute.

Something like

```
@Override
public <ReqT, RespT> ServerCall.Listener<ReqT> interceptCall(final ServerCall<ReqT, RespT> call,
                                                             final Metadata headers,
                                                             final ServerCallHandler<ReqT, RespT> next) {

    if (call.getAttributes().get(Grpc.TRANSPORT_ATTR_REMOTE_ADDR) != null) {
        final InetSocketAddress remoteAddress = (InetSocketAddress) call.getAttributes().get(Grpc.TRANSPORT_ATTR_REMOTE_ADDR);
        if (remoteAddress == null) {
            throw DeviceModuleException.create(null,"Could not get remote address of grpc client");
        }
        final Context context = Context.current().withValue(ORIGIN_IP, remoteAddress.getHostName());
        return Contexts.interceptCall(context, call, headers, next);
    }
    return next.startCall(call, headers);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I meant to fetch client IP at client-side. Not at server-side.

Comment: That's not a gRPC issue then. U can just look at how to get the IP address with your application.